# How do I call a variable from a partial template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

How do I pass a variable to a partial template and then output that variable from the template?

This is the file in views that calls the template:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/foo', :selected => "Word" %>
```

This is the partial, _foo.html.erb:

```
<%= :selected %>
```

Yet it just outputs the word "selected" instead of its value. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are passed differently into a partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/foo", :locals => { :selected => "xxx" } %>
```

and used as:

```
<%= selected %>
```

Comment: thanx. just started learning rails. i had tried different options but it hadn't worked until this.